# Proxy from nginx to node - not enough worker connections

Tags: node.js, nginx, proxy

I want to setup nginx server listening on one port, proxying the connection to a different port to a nodejs application. The problem is that I get `500` error - `worker_connections are not enough while connecting to upstream`.

Nginx config:

```
upstream node {
        server 127.0.0.1:1235;
        keepalive 8;
}

server {
        listen 1234;
        server_name http://123.123.123.123:1234 node;
        access_log off;

        location / {
                proxy_http_version 1.1;
                proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
                proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
                proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
                proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
                proxy_pass http://123.123.123.123:1234/;
                proxy_redirect off;
        }
}
```

What's wrong?

Comment: Did [my answer below](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42251579/proxy-from-nginx-to-node-not-enough-worker-connections/42252005#42252005) help you?

Answer (score 1):

You should correct your `proxy_pass` since you are proxying requests back to nginx itself.

According to your config it must be

`proxy_pass http://node/;`

Answer (score -1):

You may need to add:

```
proxy_responses 0;
```

to you nginx config.

Comment: But why though?